# plot hline at high of previous candle pine editor (trading view)

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I cant figure out how to plot a hline at high of previous candle pine. To plot a hline at price 10 i can do hline(10), and to get the high of the previous candle i can do high[1] but this does not work hline(high[1]). Also tried hline(high[1], trackprice=true)

Answer (score 2):

got it

```
plot(high[1], trackprice=true, offset=-99999)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=2
study("Horizontal line", overlay=true)
plot(high[1], trackprice=true, offset=-9999)
// trackprice=true plots horizontal line on high[1]
// offset=-9999 hides the plot
plot(close, color=#FFFFFFFF) // forces to show study
```